# Why is this mongoose populate query not working?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My user model:

```
export const UserInfoSchema = new Schema<IUserInfo>({
  name: {
    type: String,        
  },
  associatedTeams: [
    {
      type: ObjectId, // Schema.Types.ObjectId
      ref: "Team",
    },
  ],
});
```

and my Team model:

```
const TeamSchema = new Schema<ITeam>(
  {
    teamName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
  
    },
    admins: [
      {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "UserInfo",
      },
    ],
  }
);

export default models.Team || model<ITeam>("Team", TeamSchema);
```

If I save a new Team and place the ObjectId in associatedTeams on the UserInfo model, I should be able to do:

```
 if (user) { // user is a document of UserInfo model
    await user.populate("associatedTeams");
  }
```

However, this is not working, and the ObjectIds are not being populated. I've spent several hours trying to work out why - if anyone could help that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to apply populate on doc which is already in memory, you should use `execPopulate`

```js
await user.populate("associatedTeams").execPopulate()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try

Comment: Works, thank you @Puwka. I think I was looking at the docs for v 6 rather than 5....